# OS/X iconutil support for jpeg

Tags: osx-mavericks, iconutil

I am trying to use iconutil to generate icns file from iconset directory. If the icon set directory contains the required file in png format, it works. If it contains the required files in jpg format, I get

```
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 16 at scale: 1.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 16 at scale: 2.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 32 at scale: 1.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 32 at scale: 2.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 128 at scale: 1.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 128 at scale: 2.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 256 at scale: 1.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 256 at scale: 2.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 512 at scale: 1.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:warning: No image found for point size: 512 at scale: 2.
/private/tmp/MyIcon.iconset:error: Invalid iconset, no resources found in iconset.
MyIcon.iconset:error: Failed to generate ICNS.
```

Yet, the directory has these images

```
   4190 21 Aug 16:31 icon_128x128.jpg
   4958 21 Aug 16:31 icon_128x128@2x.jpg
   3938 21 Aug 16:31 icon_16x16.jpg
   3950 21 Aug 16:31 icon_16x16@2x.jpg
   4958 21 Aug 16:31 icon_256x256.jpg
   8030 21 Aug 16:31 icon_256x256@2x.jpg
   3950 21 Aug 16:31 icon_32x32.jpg
   3998 21 Aug 16:31 icon_32x32@2x.jpg
   8030 21 Aug 16:31 icon_512x512.jpg
  32606 21 Aug 16:31 icon_512x512@2x.jpg
```

Comment: Nowhere does Apple say that jpg files are supported: https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html   if that app expects pngs, then feeding it jpgs is pointless.

Comment: I did not see anywhere that it says it expects png and/or that you cannot use jpg

Comment: nowhere on that page does it show how to specify an image type, and their examples use only png, which implies that png is the only acceptable input. That does make sense. jpgs do not support transparancy, and opaque icons on the dock would look REALLY ugly.